# Linear mixed-effects model for both between (group) and within (time) but with multiple levels of the within category

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have a dataset where participants get repeatedly measured over multiple days (within effect) and they are assigned to different groups (between effect). My main research question is: **does my outcome variable significantly change between the groups over time (interaction effect)?**

However, I sometimes have multiple measurements on the same day, and sometimes only once per day. I was wondering how to correctly account for this.
Here is some example data:

```
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = rep(1:36, times=6),
                   day = rep(c("day1", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day4"), each = 36),
                   group = rep(c("active", "control", "sham"),  times=18),
                   score =  floor(runif(54, min = 0, max = 100)))
```

To answer my  main question, I would want to specify my model like this:

```
library(lme4)
lmer(score  ~ day * group, data_ex))
```

However, given the repeated measures nature, I believe I should add the subject_id as a random intercept and slope.

```
lmer(score  ~ day * group + (1|pnum), data_ex))
```

Here's however where I start to doubt, I think my model here only accounts for a random intercept.  So I end up with two questions:

1. How should I specify my R model syntax to properly add a random slope for my subject variable?
2. How do I account for the fact that some days have multiple measurements (e.g. day1 and day4 in this example) and others don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good set of questions you are asking. I'm not sure there is a right answer, but there are options you can consider, which I'll lay out below.

You are right to be aware/concerned about the fact that observations in the same day might be more correlated than observations on different days. It is hard to tell if this is an issue right now because I don't have access to your data. One thing you can do is to look at the expected correlation between scores on the same day, which is technically called an intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC). You could do that as follows:

```
m_day <- lmer(score ~ 1 + (1|day), data_ex) 

performance::icc(m_day) # gives you the expected correlation of observations from the same day, but ignores pnum
```

But you have an additional concern, which is that observations from the same person on the same day may be additionally correlated and you need to amend this model to look at that issue. The following is a three-level model of the form scores within days within persons:

```
m_day_person <- lmer(score ~ 1 + (1|pnum) + (1|pnum:day), data_ex) 

performance::icc(m_day_person) # gives you the expected correlation of scores on the same days for the same person
```

You can compare this model to a model that ignores the nesting of days within persons as such:

```
m_person <- lmer(score ~ 1 + (1|pnum), data_ex) 

anova(m_person, m_day_person) # likelihood ratio test of whether more complicated model (m_day_person) fits the data better than more parsimonious model (m_person)
```

A significant $\chi^2$ test indicates the more complicated model fits the data better. However, you could also model day as a fixed effect:

```
m_day_person2 <- lmer(score ~ 1 + day + (1|pnum), data_ex) 
anova(m_day_person, m_day_person2) #compare the fixed and random approaches
```

Ok, now you need to deal with differential effect of time depending on group. This is also a complicated issue without a straightforward answer. One approach would be to create a new variable that is a running count of the observation number for each person:

```
library(dplyr)
data_ex <- data_ex %>% arrange(pnum, day) %>% group_by(pnum) %>% mutate(obs=row_number()) %>% ungroup()
```

Then you can include that as a random slope in whichever model you choose from the above:

```
m_day_person_s <- lmer(score ~ obs*group + (obs|pnum) + (1|pnum:day), data_ex)
```

This models score as a function of obs and group (and their interaction), allowing the effect of obs to vary across pnum (`(obs|pnum)`). This may be the right way to go, but you will also want to play around with potentially allowing the `obs` variable's effect to vary across the other random effect (`obs|pnum:day`). Use model testing (i.e., `anova`) to help you arbitrate among these models.

It's possible that another parameterization could work here. Perhaps along the lines of what you initially had, using `day`. If you do so, I suggest converting `day` to a numeric if you plan to use it as a random slope.

```
data_ex <- data_ex %>% mutate(day.n = as.numeric(day))
```

Good luck!